# Anchor tag in HTML not working on single click in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my JSP code

```
<td width="25%" align="left" valign="top" class="mainContainer">
    You may start another session by clicking below <a id="loginLink" href="#" onclick="redirectURL()" target="_top"><span>Login</span></a>
</td>
```

and my JS code is

```
function redirectURL(){
    window.location.replace(appContext);
};
```

It works fine in Mozilla but in IE it works on double click. Please help.

Comment: Can you show the complete code and call?

Comment: can you please create a working example on jsfiddle and share it?

Comment: where is `appContext` defined. Any errors thrown in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor jumping is unrelated. You can disable it by stopping the default functioning of anchor tag.

`<td width="25%" align="left" valign="top" class="mainContainer">
    You may start another session by clicking below <a id="loginLink" href="#" onclick="redirectURL(event)" target="_top"><span>Login</span></a>
</td>`

```
function redirectURL(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  window.location.replace(appContext);
};
```